# ошибка near SqLite

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlite3

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablica(Nomenclature,Initial_balance Кол-во|Сумма,Incoming Кол-во|Сумма TEXT, Consumption Кол-во|Сумма TEXT,Final_Balance Кол-во|Сумма TEXT)")
```

Создаю таблицу и выдает на этой строчке ошибку  OperationalError('near "-": syntax error')

Что делать? Уже много раз меняла названия и столбцов и самой таблицы, ничего не выходит

Comment: Ну например изучить основы SQL? `Кол-во` очевидно является некорректным типом столбца, и использовать такую конструкцию просто бессмысленно.

Answer (score 0):

я бы сказал, что вы используете кириллические буквы или недопустимые символы в названиях колонок. Попробуйте назвать их только латинскими буквами и без пробелом и символов.